# R: How to extract everything after first occurence of a dot (.)

Tags: r, replace

I need to extract from a string such as `outside.HLA.DR.highpass` the part *after* the first dot, yielding `HLA.DR.highpass`.

Importantly, the middle part of the string, outside.xxx.highpass might or might not have additional dots, e.g. `outside.CD19.highpass` should yield in `CD19.highpass` as well.

I got similar steps where extraction of the first part I do with `sub(".[^.]+$", "", "outside.HLA.DR.highpass" )` to return `"outside.HLA.DR"`. However, I fail to adapt it so that it returns only the part of the string after the first dot?
any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution for extraction of the first area is correct. Simply apply a similar rule:

```
sub("^[^.]+.","","outside.HLA.DR.highpass")
```

Should return the desired string.

Comment: thank you so much! the syntax of sub is still cryptic to me, but I like both solutions given here using sub!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a non-greedy regex operator here to capture the start of the sentence (`^`), followed by the fewest possible characters (`.*?`) followed by a literal dot (`\\.`)

```r
sub("^.*?\\.", "", "outside.HLA.DR.highpass")
# "HLA.DR.highpass"
```

Comment: this is perfect! I could not find this pattern anywhere. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MaBar1 feel free to accept this or another answer that works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with `stringr` that will work on a vector.

```r
library(stringr)

s <- c("outside.HLA.DR.highpass", "outside.CD19.highpass")

str_sub(
  s, 
  start = str_locate(s, fixed("."))[, 1] + 1, 
  end   = str_length(s)
)
#> [1] "HLA.DR.highpass" "CD19.highpass"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: `sub` also works on a vector.

Comment: thanks! Im always searching for a more readable code when extracting strings, so could you explain what the two lines ''start='' and ''end='' do?

Comment: No prob.  It's just the starting and ending positions of the string subset.  The start is the position of the "." plus one, the end is the string length (last character).